# How to disable double click on table row

Tags: jquery

I have datagrid with certain rows. I just wanted to disable double click on table row using jQuery. how to implement it

Answer (score 1):

Well do this:

```
$('tr').dblclick(function(){
   return false; // does both event.stopPropogation as well as event.preventDefault
});
```